# Scala main class with futures not terminating

Tags: scala, future, slick, actor, actorsystem

I have a scala main class

```
object Job extends App {

         def myProcedure() = {
             sqlu"""CALL `dbName`.`update_history();"""
         }

         implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
         implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
         implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
         implicit val session: SlickSession = SlickSession.forConfig("my-mysql")
         val proc = session.db.run(myProcedure))
          
         val terminatedF = proc.flatMap { rec =>
              println("value of the procedure ::" + rec)
              session.close()
              system.terminate()
         }
         Await.result(terminatedF, Duration.Inf)
          println("terminated :::")
     }
```

I see that the value of `rec` gets printed, and also `terminated :::` i.e. last line also gets printed. However the program does not end.  Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: You probably need to "close" or "terminate" that session somehow. I don't know slick, but this snippet doesn't look write to me, leaving the `session` thing just sitting around like this. That's not how code accessing external resources usually looks. To your question, it probably has a thread pool inside, that prevents your program from exiting. Try sifting through slick documentation looking for session management specifically.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however I figured out the problem. It had nothing to do with slick but had something to do to make JVM exit gracefully

Comment: `System.exit` is _the opposite_ if "exiting gracefully". You should not need it, and the reason you do probably actually does have to do with slick :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with user defined threads.

I used `Await.result` on the last Future and then did `sys.exit(0)`.
Also in `build.sbt`

I used

```
fork in run := true
```

This perfectly works